# -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] makes app CRASH

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

We are getting an error when trying to delete a folder on startup. We are removing a folder placed in documents used to store cache-data. Any idea why it is crashing?

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x364b62d0 __unlink + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x364b46a6 unlink + 2
2   libremovefile.dylib     0x313099c8 __removefile_process_file + 232
3   libremovefile.dylib     0x31309a50 __removefile_tree_walker + 100
4   libremovefile.dylib     0x313090f4 removefile + 88
5   Foundation              0x3156c11a -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] + 138
6   Foundation              0x31551d14 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 652
7   Foundation              0x31551a78 -[NSOperation start] + 16
8   Foundation              0x3156bfda -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 46
9   VG                      0x0004f030 +[VGFileManager removeOldCacheFolder] + 319536
10  VG                      0x00003e1c -[VGAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 11804
11  UIKit                   0x31de481a -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 766
12  UIKit                   0x31ddeb5e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 266
13  UIKit                   0x31db37d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
14  UIKit                   0x31db320e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
15  UIKit                   0x31db2c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
16  GraphicsServices        0x34720e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
17  CoreFoundation          0x30ba5a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
18  CoreFoundation          0x30ba7838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
19  CoreFoundation          0x30ba8606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
20  CoreFoundation          0x30b38ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
21  CoreFoundation          0x30b38dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
22  UIKit                   0x31dddd42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
23  UIKit                   0x31ddb800 UIApplicationMain + 664
24  VG                      0x0000bd96 0x1000 + 44438
25  VG                      0x00003990 0x1000 + 10640
```

This is the function called on "9".

```
+ (void)removeOldCacheFolder {

    BOOL oldCacheFolderRemoved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kVGFileCacheFolder_1_2];

    if(!oldCacheFolderRemoved){
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get documents folder  
        NSString *cacheDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kVGFileCacheFolder_1_2]; 

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cacheDirectory]) {
            NSError *error = nil;

            if (!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:cacheDirectory error:&error])) {
                ELog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            else{
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kVGFileCacheFolder_1_2];
            }
        }
    }

    BOOL oldSQLFileDeleted = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kVGFileDb_1_3];

    if(!oldSQLFileDeleted){

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get documents folder

        NSString *sqlFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kVGFileDb_1_3]; 

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlFile]) {
            NSError *error = nil;

            if (!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:sqlFile error:&error])) {
                ELog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            else{
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kVGFileDb_1_3];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just discovered this process can take 2 minutes...

Comment: What is the crash message?  Step through in Xcode and determine the line it crashes on.

Comment: It only crashes in the one which is currently in appstore, but it is when calling -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]. It could be when trying to delete the "sqlFile" or when trying to delete the "cacheDirectory"

Comment: Presumably ELog is valid in the store code?  As an aside, this code gives me an example for my next CocoaHeads presentation: refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we're getting killed by the iOS watchdog, any app that takes too long to launch gets terminated. Could it be a too time consuming process?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was happening? Having the same issue.

Comment: Looks like in situations with large number and or size of files this can take some time and is not appropriate to do on the main thread.

Comment: Yep! That's it! I remember now.. I was blocking the main thread for a long period of time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special caches folder that iOS maintains - it's contents is not backed up whereas you data will be backed up when syncing.

```
NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
```

You trimmed of the exception type from you dump. You could perhaps learn something about the crash from the exception type and code.

I read through the version 1.2 section of the code and honestly it looks just fine. Check your define for kVGFileCacheFolder_1_2 - I assume something like @"file.dat" which is also fine.

Check that the file is closed and there is no other ongoing operations on the file.

Comment: thanks.. hard to say really what happens. The constant is pointing to a path for a folder.

Comment: If it's a folder, perhaps you could iterate through the files to see what file is the offending file. Use try/catch and liberal NSLog's. And you are sure that the database is not running off the files in that directory?

Comment: It could well be, but after reading the documentation NSFileManager should handle other proccesses using a file which actions is taken upon such as delete.